# Why doesn't strtok() return false when it reaches the end of the string?

Tags: php, string, boolean

I'm using `strtok()` function to tokenise a string and understand that the `token` could be a `falsey` value so must be compared with `=== / !==` for boolean checking.

However I'm getting into a situation where the `token` never evaluates to `false`

```
<?php

$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 0 consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ullamcorper quam sit amet maximus ornare. Proin dignissim ante eu finibus faucibus. Proin fringilla consequat metus, et imperdiet purus interdum ut. Donec efficitur convallis nisl at luctus. Duis maximus, orci ac congue volutpat, urna nisi dictum nulla, nec auctor tellus libero vel sapien. Nam scelerisque nibh mi, sed posuere libero tincidunt sit amet. Mauris blandit nulla at volutpat dapibus. Donec ac libero sollicitudin, cursus dolor nec, cursus quam.";

$delimiters = " \n\t.,?!;:";

$word = strtolower(strtok($str, $delimiters));

while ($word !== false) {
    echo "|" . $word . "|" . "\n";;
    $word = strtolower(strtok($delimiters));
}
```

A broken example is available here https://3v4l.org/u35vL

Comment: you are assigning to the variable `$word` the returning value of `strtolower` and not of `strtok`. Not sure if this is the error but did you tried to remove the call to `strtolower`?

Comment: @terencehill you are correct, however someone else has posted your comment as an answer.

Comment: That's fine. I'm not a php programmer and I just guessed the error but didn't know the cause. The answer correctly address both the problem and the solution. But thanks for the comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say *"However I'm getting into a situation where the token never evaluates to false"* but you never check the value returned by [`strtok()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php). Instead, you pass that value to [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php):

```
$word = strtolower(strtok($delimiters));
```

`strtolower()` expects a string as input. When the value passed to it is not a string it is converted to a string before anything else. Accordingly, a `FALSE` value returned by `strtok()` is converted to the empty string (`''`) and passed to `strtolower()` that returns it back.

A correct usage of `strtok()` will be:

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 0 consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ullamcorper quam sit amet maximus ornare. Proin dignissim ante eu finibus faucibus. Proin fringilla consequat metus, et imperdiet purus interdum ut. Donec efficitur convallis nisl at luctus. Duis maximus, orci ac congue volutpat, urna nisi dictum nulla, nec auctor tellus libero vel sapien. Nam scelerisque nibh mi, sed posuere libero tincidunt sit amet. Mauris blandit nulla at volutpat dapibus. Donec ac libero sollicitudin, cursus dolor nec, cursus quam.";

$delimiters = " \n\t.,?!;:";

$word = strtok($str, $delimiters);
while ($word !== false) {
    echo "|" . strtolower($word) . "|" . "\n";
    $word = strtok($delimiters);
}
```

Another way to achieve the same result is to use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$pieces = preg_split("/[ \n\t.,?!;:]+/", $str);
foreach ($pieces as $word) {
    echo "|" . strtolower($word) . "|" . "\n";
}
```

`preg_split()` returns an array containing all the words.